# Bromine radical reaction with an alkene - What factors determine whether radical addition occurs as oppose to radical abstraction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, radicals

[image]

From what I can tell, radical addition occurs when using HBr + Organic peroxides as reagents, and radical abstraction occurs when using trace amounts of bromine radicals (generated by NBS, trace HBr and UV).

However, in the end, a bromine radical is reacting with an alkene. Why / how do the preceding reagents determine the regioselectivity of the radical reaction?